# Couchbase : insufficient memory to satisfy memory quota for the services (requested quota is 2048MB, maximum allowed quota for the node is 1592MB)

Tags: couchbase

Getting this error while trying to create a new couchbase cluster

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. While I have edited your question here for now, please ensure that in future you elaborate your questions and provide specific details rather than just adding the screenshot of error message.

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are getting while creating a new cluster is because you are **trying to allocate more memory than available/allowed** while creating your cluster.

[image]

For eg, if you see the above configuration while creating the cluster, you would see that the **Max Allowed Quota** is 3152MB, and the **Total Quota** that's showing up is more than the allowed quota. So in your similar case, you would need to either uncheck any of the features that's not required for you or decrease the memory in the input boxes so that the **Total Quota** comes below the **Max Allowed Quota**.